# Block incoming ssh with a reply message

Tags: ssh, firewall

I want to block all the incoming ssh to my system from a particular set of ips and send them a typical message saying something of sort:

```
You don't have permissions to access this server as the specified user. Contact admin to get appropriate access".
```

I know we can block incoming ssh using firewall rules, but how do i block a particular set (please note that the ips in this set may not be continuous, for eg the set could contain following ip ranges or even individual ips:

```
{192.168.1.1-9, 192.168.15-20, 192.168.1.25, ...})
```

Then send the above message to those ips as mentioned earlier.

PS: I am using ubuntu-14.04

Comment: Unless there is a particular need or setting (for instance, a different department), I do not find a particular good idea to give *any* kind of service, including error messages, to netblocks who are not supposed to have it. The less you expose a service, the more secure the server is. Security is the sum of all parts.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, Its just for fun and learning :)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/286287/custom-error-message-for-sshd

Comment: You may still do it, but it will be a more convoluted setup. Will try to come back later on.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, so you mean to say there is no hack possible other than passing the ssh login off to the unix login command and let it handle it?

Comment: It is a possible solution. There might be others.

Comment: You can't block connections and also send data back.  To send any data back you have to allow a connection.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I don't think that's correct. I think you can obviously send data back to the ip which was blocked (since you always know the ip from which connection is being requested) and after that it's upto that ip to accept or reject the message. Isn't it so? I am still new to this, so please ignore my lack of experience, if any.

Comment: @tom To even get to the point of negotiating an SSH connection, you have to allow a TCP connection.  To send data back to the originating host - even a banner - you have to allow that SSH connection to succeed.  The only point of doing this is to tell someone **you want to communicate with** what they need to do to get access.

Answer (score 2):

In your sshd_config, you could setup a Match block to issue a custom banner (file path), and explicitly set the MaxAuthTries to zero.

```
Match Address 192.168.1.?,192.168.1.15,192.168.1.4?
    Banner /etc/ssh_refused_banner
    MaxAuthTries 0
```

I don't believe that the Match pattern list can do ranges, but wildcards ? and * should work, as well as subnets like 192.168.1.0/24. It may be easier to match on an entire subnet and explicitly whitelist the allowed addresses, like "192.168.1.0/24,!192.168.1.12,!192.168.1.35"

Comment: By doing that, you've already allowed the connection.  You just automatically terminate it - after you allow it through.  And if the entity at the other end of the connection hasn't managed to exploit any vulnerability that may exist on your system.  If you don't want to give them access, just block them.  You'd only do this to send a message to someone.  If you don't want to communicate with those IPs you shouldn't get to the point of allowing any connections of any type.